# How do I control formatting of email replies?

Tags: email, thunderbird

90% of the time when I get an email reply from someone, my original message in their reply is formatted as follows:

```
On [date], [my name] <[my email]> wrote:

> [What I wrote]
```

However, every time I compose an email reply to someone, their original message in my reply is formatted as follows:

```
----- Original Message -----
> From: "[their name]" <[their email]>
> To: "[my name]" <[my email]>
> Sent: <date>
> Subject: <subject>
>
> [What they wrote]
```

I would like to understand what gives rise to this difference in formatting, and how to change the formatting of my replies to look like everyone else's replies.

My natural first suspicion is that the formatting is a function of the email client, but I've seen this behaviour across different email clients I've used, (including Yahoo Mail, Hotmail, Thunderbird, and Zimbra), and there is something fishy about my replies being formatted differently from just about everyone else's.

**How do you configure Thunderbird to choose between the above two formats**?

Comment: If they send you an email that's in plain-text format, and you hit "reply" most email clients will assume/default to plain-text for your reply.

Comment: @techie007: Both of the above formats are plain-text, they're just different ways of formatting the plain text.

Comment: @Nifle: why did you revert my edit? It was trying to address the reason for which the question was put on hold.